# OpenShift Pro: Binary Deployment - Can It Be Done From Git

Tags: deployment, binary, openshift

I am in the final phase of my migration from **OpenShift v2** to **OpenShift Pro**.

I have a **DEVELOPMENT** version of the webapp in **Eclipse Oxygen**. The **TEST** version is deployed to **OpenShift Pro** via a push to **Github** of the source code (the normal way).

For the **LIVE** version I export a war to the '**deployments**' folder and do a **binary deployment** to **OpenShift Pro** like this:

```
oc new-build --image-stream=jboss-webserver30-tomcat8-openshift --binary=true --name=live
oc start-build live --from-dir=/Users/lyndon/git/mmjlive/deployments
```

It works very nicely...

But I would like to be able to do this using a git push. I have created a project (mmjlive) in Eclipse that only has a **configuration** folder and a **deployments** folder (contains the war).

My questions are:-

Is it possible to trigger a binary deployment build from a git push?

If it is, then what do I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are asking, usually you would use a Jenkins setup if needing to do something like that. The git push to the repo could trigger the Jenkins workflow, which would check out your code, build the war file and then trigger the binary build. OpenShift does support being able to host Jenkins to enable this, but don't right now have a good link can drop you which explains it all. You might find a bit about it in https://www.openshift.com/promotions/devops-with-openshift.html

Comment: This article seems to do something similar to what I want. The second option uses git and builds from a war: https://blog.openshift.com/binary-deployments-openshift-3/